# move (or ren) several folders into a one folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

i have 3 folders (dir1, dir2, dir3). And i want to rename or move this folders (content) to a new folder (dirfinal)
Example

```
if exist c:\dir1 move /y c:\dir1 c:\dirfinal
if exist c:\dir2 move /y c:\dir2 c:\dirfinal
if exist c:\dir3 move /y c:\dir3 c:\dirfinal
```

Inside dir1 is abc.txt, work1 (folder)

Inside dir2 is def.txt, work1 (folder)

Inside dir3 is abc.txt, work2 (folder)

And the result i expect is:

c:\dirfinal\

abc.txt

def.txt

work1

work2

but I do not get the result

I want move all the content of the 3 folders (dir1, dir2, dir3), to dirfinal (not the folder.. the folder dir1, dir2, dir3 need to remove them), overwriting any files or folders repeated without asking (example: abc.txt is the same in dir1 and dir3). And how I can automate this process (in the future to add new folders)

thanks

Comment: Try specifying the filename(s) rather than the directory name. `if exist c:\dir1\* (move /y c:\dir1\* c:\dirfinal)`

Comment: ok. update question

Comment: Make a backup of the source directory files, then try `robocopy /E /MOVE dir1 ..\dirfinal`.

Comment: Some versions of Windows do not have robocopy. I need a compatible solution

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if exist C:\dir1 move /y C:\dir1\*.* C:\dirfinal
if exist C:\dir2 move /y C:\dir2\*.* C:\dirfinal
if exist C:\dir3 move /y C:\dir3\*.* C:\dirfinal
```

this will move all files from C:\dir1, Dir2 and Dir3 to C:\dirfinal

Comment: I need move all folders (dir1, dir2 and dir3) to dirfinal. Not only dir1

Comment: There you go buddy

Comment: but you have put the same thing in my question. I see no automated solution. Just repeat folder by folder